# Lock features/apps in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to lock device features programmatically, that is, i am working on an application that locks the device features/apps everytime it runs , please list me or let me know what all features we can lock through code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API available on Windows Phone to lock any feature or app. Pretty much anything that is outside of the scope of your app (like changing a system setting, turning on/off the device, preventing an app to launch...) is forbidden.

Comment: but there is one app that locks photogallery in it http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/photo-lock/569edbb4-aaa1-43c6-8dd7-5dae8ad65bef

Comment: @AmanKhandelwal That does not lock the pictures from the Pictures Hub, it's just an app that can save pictures for you in its own storage, and lock that. From the app description `* Unfortunately due to limitations in Windows Phone after importing a photo you will have to delete it manually from the Pictures Hub. 

** Unfortunately due to limitations in Windows Phone, you cannot import videos from your library. If you want to protect a video in the app, you must record it inside Photo Lock.`